# Django JSON serializable error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

With the following code below, There is an error saying

```
      File "/home/user/web_pro/info/views.py", line 184, in headerview,
      raise TypeError("%r is not JSON serializable" % (o,))
      TypeError: <lastname: jerry> is not JSON serializable
```

In the models code

```
  header(models.Model):
   firstname = models.ForeignKey(Firstname)
   lastname = models.ForeignKey(Lastname)
```

In the views code

```
  headerview(request):
       header = header.objects.filter(created_by=my_id).order_by(order_by)[offset:limit]


      l_array = []
      l_array_obj = []
      for obj in header:

           l_array_obj = [obj.title, obj.lastname ,obj.firstname ]
           l_array.append(l_array_obj)
      dictionary_l.update({'Data': l_array}) ; 
      return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dictionary_l), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

what is this  error and how to resolve this?

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick read is that obj.lastname is a Lastname model not a String.  You probably need to say something like:

```
l_array_obj = [..., obj.lastname.value, .... ]
```

to get the string value, rather than the Model object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Django's [own serialization functionality](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)?